# Possible to purchase credit reports more than once a year?

Tags: united-states, credit-report

I live in the U.S. and although I am *well aware* that I am entitled to a [free annual credit report](https://www.annualcreditreport.com/index.action) once a year, I am open and willing to **purchase** my credit reports (from each bureau) more frequently than that.

**Is this possible to do, and if so, how/where?** On AnnualCreditReport.com and on the individual bureau websites, I can't find any links for doing this.

**Please note:** I am *not* interested in going through one of these middlemen services (like CreditKarma, etc.) unless -- for some crazy reason -- its the *only* way to buy/obtain your credit report outside of your yearly freebie from AnnualCreditReport.com...

Thanks in advance for any-and-all help!

Comment: Go to https://www.transunion.com and click on "My Credit Score & Report". Sign up to pay $24.95/month and get "UNLIMITED Score & Report access — updates available daily".  I did that for about six months, and then decided it wasn't needed anymore.

Comment: You actually can't get your credit reports from credit karma or others, they just do a soft pull of the most important metrics and do some math to approximate your credit score. It's largely accurate and sufficient for most people, but it's not what you would get from transunion itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible to do, and if so, how/where?

Yes, on any of the credit bureau websites. (Equifax/TransUnion/Experian).

What they all seem to be doing now is offering a subscription product for $20-25/month that gets you a 3-bureau credit report among other features, which you can then cancel at any time.

Starting in 2020 for seven years you can get up to 6 free credit reports per year through Equifax as part of their data breach settlement, those are available to you whether or not you were affected by the data breach.